# Angular 11 - Update sidebar component after logging in

Tags: angular, typescript

I am just getting into Angular and I am slowly trying to understand what's going on. Basically, I have a sidebar component which is always loaded. My issue is that after I login, the sidebar does not update:

[this is my sidebar text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jce4.png)

When I login, the register and login text should be hidden and display like this:

[sidebar after login & refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Fjg.png)

The text properly updates after fully refreshing the page (F5).

Also, when using the logout text, the sidebar properly updates to "login and register" without having to refresh.

Some code that hopefully will provide some insight:

**side-bar.component.html**

```
<p *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated">{{message}}</p> 
<li *ngIf="!authService.isAuthenticated"><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
<li *ngIf="!authService.isAuthenticated"><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
<li *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated"><a routerLink="/home" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
```

**side-bar.component.ts**

```
message = ''
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated)
    {
        this.authService.getUser()
        console.log("user is logged in")
        this.message = `Welcome`
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("user is not logged in")
    }
    
}



logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout()
}
```

**auth-service.service.ts**

```
get isAuthenticated() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY)
}

logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.TOKEN_KEY)
    this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/logout', {})
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
}

login(user: string, pass: string) {    
    const data = {
        username: user,
        password: pass
    }

    this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/login', data, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            console.log(res)
            localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, res.token.value)
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
        }
    )
}

getUser() {
    this.http.get(this.API_URL + '/user', {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }
    )
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call is asynchronous and the hook `ngOnInit` is invoked only once when the component is initialized. The elegant way would be make the authentication check also be asynchronous. Additionally I'd also move the subscriptions to the components instead of the service.

Try the following

**Service**

```js
isAuthenticatedSrc: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
  this.isAuthenticatedSrc.asObservable();
}

login(user: string, pass: string): Observable<any> {
  const data = {
    username: user,
    password: pass
  }

  this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/login', data, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
    tap((res: any) => {
      this.isAuthenticatedSrc.next(true);
      localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, res.token.value);
    }),
    catchError((error: any) => {
      this.isAuthenticatedSrc.next(false);
      // handle error
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}

logout(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/logout', {}).pipe(
    tap(() => localStorage.removeItem(this.TOKEN_KEY))
  );
}

getUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.API_URL + '/user', { withCredentials: true });
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.login(user, pass).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => this.router.navigateByUrl('/home'),
    error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
  });
}
```

**side-bar.component.ts**

```js
logout() {
  this.authService.logout().subscribe({
    next: () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/home'),
    error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
  });
}
```

**side-bar.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(authService.isAuthenticated | async) as authenticated; else unauthenticated">
  <p>Welcome</p>
  <li><a routerLink="/home" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #unauthenticated>
  <li><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
<ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create getter for message in your component and not setting it any more through ngOnInit.

Something like:

```
get message() {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated ? 'Welcome' : '';
}
```

The other and the better way is to use observables and change the value through observable.